# label_bquote works fine on columns but not rows

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I have `label_bquote` working fine for labelling facet columns but I am confused on why it incorrectly labels the facet rows.

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, cty)) + geom_point()+
  facet_grid(drv ~ cyl,as.table = F,scales="free")
```

This has the correct labels but for my actual data I would like to add some text to each label.

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, cty)) + geom_point()+
  facet_grid(drv ~ cyl,as.table = F,labeller =label_bquote(cols=italic(N)[e1]==.(cyl),rows=italic(N)[e0]==.(drv)),scales="free")
```

This correctly adds the `Ne0=` to each facet column as well as the `Ne1=` to each row. The issue is I lose the correct label in the rows as they change to 1,2,3.

I have the issue narrowed down to the `italic(N)[e1]==` as if I remove that the correct labels return.

Where am I going wrong or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: It works if you change the `as.table = F`